# How to remove google search results for 303 redirect?

Tags: redirect, http-headers, seo, robots.txt, noindex

I run a dynamic site that may or may not redirect a certain route based on user preferences.

Let's say it's `http://clientname.example.com/maybe`. Our backend has a response for `/maybe`, but if the client decides they would rather use their site for the information on that page, we instead use a 303 Redirect to their page on a separate domain.

All of our content pages use the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag, so google will not index any of our pages. HOWEVER, when I search google for "site:our_domain_name.com", I get a bunch of results that all trace back to those dynamic routes that return a 303. When I click on the search results in google, the 303 is followed as expected and I arrive at the client's site. What I want, is for my piece of the puzzle to not show in results at all.

I was troubleshooting it this morning, and I realized that our noindex meta tag was obviously not being seen by the robot as it was following the redirect, so I added a rule on the server that adds the '`X-Robot-Tag: noindex`' header to redirect responses.

Is that enough? If I wait long enough, will those search results be removed?

Comment: Are you also blocking them in robots.txt? or are you just using robots meta tags and the x-robots-tag header?

Comment: Just meta tags and the header I just added...no robots.txt.

Comment: Good. Then you should be fine, at least with major search engines. It may take a few weeks though.

Comment: Great! I'll just keep an eye on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Is that enough? If I wait long enough, will those search results be removed?
```

No because if an external page links to your site, Google will follow the link to your site, then your 303 (if your return such a code) and won't see the `noindex`.

Don't return a 303 for Google bots and you should be fine. It may take a bit of time, because Google needs to reprocess the page and see the `noindex` to remove it.